# Status Bar When Screen is Locked android

Tags: android, screen, statusbar, locked

I am starting activity with application context when screen is locked. However Status bar is not usable, doesnt get dropped down. Is there any way to make status bar and notifications usable when screen is locked ? (ICS-Android)

Comment: If the user has some lock security enabled (schema, pin code, etc.), status bar is disabled until the credential has been entered

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be done. This is a security feature of android, if the notification bar could pulled down while the user has the device locked, then it opens the user to security issues as personal information may be in the notification bar such as missed calls, text messages and emails etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. GravityBox has an option to allow this.

However I'd be interested on what file you'd have to mod inside the SystemUI/res folder in order to make it work without Gravitybox...